# DataTable 'i' displaying as 'filtered from NaN total entries'

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have an issue with the 'Show X of X records' in one of my `Datatables`.

This is my code

```
{
 'ordering': true,  // Column ordering
 'info':     true,  // Bottom left status text
 'retrieve': true,
 'serverSide': true,
 "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
 "ajax": {
     "url": '/ajax/reporting.adsl.datatable.php?' + $('#gridFilter').serialize(),
     "data": function (params) {
         sortColumns = [];
         for (let i = 0; i < params.order.length; i++) {
             col = params.order[i].column;
             dir = params.order[i].dir;
             sortColumns.push(params.columns[col].data, dir);
         }

         data = [];

         $.each(params.columns, function (k, v) {
             // only send params we have marked as searchable
             if (v.searchable === true) {
                 data.push(v);
             }
         });

         params.columns = data;
         params.filter = params.search.value;
         params.order = sortColumns;
         return params;
     },
     "dataSrc": function ( data ) {
         if (parseInt(data.recordsTotal) > 0 && parseInt(data.recordsTotal) <= 25) {
             $('#orderPagination1').hide()
             $("#gridFilter :input").prop("disabled", false);
         } else if (data.aaData.length === 0) {
             $('#downloadcsv, #broadbandreport_info, .bottom').hide()
             $("#gridFilter :input").prop("disabled", true);
         } else {
             $('#downloadcsv, #broadbandreport_info, .bottom').show()
             $("#gridFilter :input").prop("disabled", false);
         }

         return data.aaData;
     }
 },
 "order": [[ 0, "desc"]],
 "iDisplayLength": 25,
 aoColumns: [
     { mData: 'orderref',searchable: true, name: 'orderref' },
     { mData: 'charge', searchable: false, name: 'charge', render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( '.', '.', 2, '£' )},

     <?php if( (isset($_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']) && $_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']=='Customer') || !empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_CUST'])): ?>
     <?php else: ?>
         { mData: 'revenue', sDefaultContent: '0.00', searchable: false, render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( '.', '.', 2, '£' ) },
     <?php endif;?>

     { mData: 'customer_company', searchable: true, name: 'c_company'},
     { mData: 'report_status', searchable: false},
     { mData: 'orderdate', searchable: false },
     { mData: 'committeddate', searchable: false },
     { mData: 'actions', searchable: false}
 ],
 "aoColumnDefs": [
     // Admin Level
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']) && $_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']=='Admin' && empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_RES'])): ?>
         { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 ] },

     // Admin @ Reseller
     <?php elseif(isset($_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']) && $_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']=='Admin' && !empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_RES']) && empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_CHAN']) && empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_CUST'])): ?>
         { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 ] },

     // Admin @ Channel
     <?php elseif(isset($_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']) && $_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']=='Admin' && !empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_CHAN']) && empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_CUST'])): ?>
         { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 ] },

     // Admin @ Customer
     <?php elseif(isset($_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']) && $_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']=='Admin' && !empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_CUST'])): ?>
         { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] },
     <?php endif; ?>

     //// Reseller @ Reseller
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']) && $_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']=='Reseller' && empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_CHAN'])): ?>
         { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 ] },
     <?php endif; ?>

     // Reseller @ Channel
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']) && $_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']=='Reseller' && !empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_CHAN']) && empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_CUST'])): ?>
         { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 ] },
     <?php endif; ?>

     // Reseller @ Customer
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']) && $_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']=='Reseller' && !empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_CUST'])): ?>
         { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] },
     <?php endif; ?>

     // Channel @ Channel
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']) && $_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']=='Channel' && empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_CUST'])): ?>
         { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 ] },
     <?php endif; ?>

     // Channel @ Customer
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']) && $_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']=='Channel' && !empty($_SESSION['V_CUR_CUST'])): ?>
         { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] },
     <?php endif; ?>

     // Customer
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']) && $_SESSION['V_LVL_LOGIN']=='Customer'): ?>
         { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] },
     <?php endif; ?>
 ],

 //sDom: '<"clear">ifrt <"bottom"lp>',
 sDom: "<'row'<'#col1.col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-muted'i><'#col2.col-xs-12 col-md-6'f>>rt<'bottom'lp>",

 "fnDrawCallback": function () {
     $('#col1').css({ 'margin-top': '1rem', 'padding-left': 0 });
     $('#col2').css('padding-right', 0)
 }
```

}

[image]

I need to use the `serverSide` so no answers saying don't use it unless you can provide a solution please yet on my next page using the EXACT same code above I

[image]

I have taken all my code for the working page and dropped it in and still not working for whatever reason and I need it too.

Are there any suggestions as all the solutions in `Google` do not work for me

This is my `JSON` returned

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the JSON response being sent from the server when you see `NaN`? (An [example](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data) of what I am referring to, for reference). Specifically, what values is the server providing for `recordsTotal`, and `recordsFiltered` in its response? And does the `draw` value match the one sent in the request?

Comment: Just a side note (not related to your question), but I'd recommend updating the DataTable option names [from Hungarian to camelCase](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert). So, `sDom` becomes `dom` and so on. This is optional since the names are backwards-compatible. But recommended for clarity.

Comment: @andrewJames - cheers for that i have changed them. The `DT` was created by another DEV and I hadn't noticed. I always use `camelCase`. I have also added a screenshot of my returned data

Comment: Following your update: Your JSON has null values for `recordsTotal`, and `recordsFiltered`. If you fix that in your server-side PHP code (not shown in the question) then you will fix the display issue. And also where is `draw`? That is missing (from your screenshot). You have chosen (or are required) to use server-side processing - so the server needs to provide these values.

Comment: Generally, please provide textual data (e.g. JSON) as [text not as screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365).